# Timeout after sending random amount of requests

Tags: neo4j

I'm using local Neo4j server with Bolt protocol. I'm sending relation creation queries in a loop from a PHP project. After 5 - 10 queries it gives the error below. However, it executes the queries before this error.

```
ERROR [o.n.b.t.TransportSelectionHandler] Fatal error occurred when initialising pipeline: [id: 0xa078f8de, L:/127.0.0.1:7687 ! R:/127.0.0.1:59148] Terminated connection '[id: 0xa078f8de, L:/127.0.0.1:7687 ! R:/127.0.0.1:59148]' as the client failed to authenticate within 30000 ms.
org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.BoltConnectionFatality: Terminated connection '[id: 0xa078f8de, L:/127.0.0.1:7687 ! R:/127.0.0.1:59148]' as the client failed to authenticate within 30000 ms.
    at org.neo4j.bolt.transport.pipeline.AuthenticationTimeoutHandler.channelIdle(AuthenticationTimeoutHandler.java:74)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$ReaderIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:504)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AbstractIdleTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:476)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

For fixing that, I tried setting `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` but same error occurs again.

I also thought that It might be a rate limiting - throttling mechanism in Neo4j but I can't find any option related to that.

Also here is my query execution function:

```
private static function runQuery($query)
{
    $client = ClientBuilder::create()
        ->withDriver('bolt', config('neo4j.server_url'))
        ->build();

    return json_decode(json_encode($client->run($query)))->result;
}
```

Update: It seems this error does not occur when HTTP is used instead of Bolt protocol.

Comment: Are you using the neo4j PHP client? I am the author of the library. The default socket timeout has been increased in the newer version. Are you on version 2.3.3?

Comment: My composer.json has "laudis/neo4j-php-client": "^2.2", which is currently 2.3.3 in my project. Some answers said that there might be idle open bolt connections and port limit might be reached in the system. Do I have to manually clear them?

Comment: Thank you for the information. It looks like it might be a bug. Can you post an issue on github for the client? I will take care of it from there